# Logging class doesn't let Amazon SNS message to be send

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am using Amazon's SNS service to send messages to phones. The development is being made with Java and Amazon's SDK.

At first it was working perfectly, but now the messages have stopped being send, and the following error appears on the console:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

The java code that sends messages is the same one from the example that can be found in [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html#sms_publish_sdk):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient();
        String message = "My SMS message";
        String phoneNumber = "+1XXX5550100";
        Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes = 
                new HashMap<String, MessageAttributeValue>();
        //<set SMS attributes>
        sendSMSMessage(snsClient, message, phoneNumber, smsAttributes); }

public static void sendSMSMessage(AmazonSNSClient snsClient, String message, String phoneNumber, Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes) {
        PublishResult result = snsClient.publish(new PublishRequest()
                        .withMessage(message)
                        .withPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                        .withMessageAttributes(smsAttributes));
        System.out.println(result); // Prints the message ID.
}
```

Upon research, I have tried using the logging solution found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-logging.html), which sets up a log4js.properties file, and the same solution in a [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=44891&tstart=0) from AWS Developer Forums. None of them worked.

I have also tried adding `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory`, as the error was caused by it (and StackOveflow other questions suggested it). After that, another error was caused, saying I needed to add `com.fasterxml.jackson.core`. I added, and it asked for `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind`. Added it again, and it asked for another. Upon the 5th (no joke) jar added I gave up.

AWS's documentation is terrible. Dependencies to get a program to work are often located in completely separated pages, and the developers have to find that out for themselves.

I have already set up a user with key and secret key.

Can I disable logging so that this error doesn't occur? If not, what jars do I have to add as dependencies to get this code to work?

Comment: What is your build environment like?  Are you not using ivy/maven/gradle to manage these dependencies?  I haven't had to worry about manually adding dependencies for years now - you're doing something very wrong.

Comment: I'm using maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got something else going on then.  For a simple pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>sns</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.hotjoe.aws</groupId>
    <name>SNS Sample</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.202</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and then running `mvn dependency:tree` I get:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ sns ---
[INFO] com.hotjoe.aws:sns:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:jar:1.11.202:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:jar:1.11.202:compile
[INFO]    +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.202:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.4:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO]    |  +- software.amazon.ion:ion-java:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.7.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.7:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.6.7:compile
[INFO]    |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO]    \- com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:jar:1.11.202:compile
```

As you can see, commons logging is included along with Jackson libraries.

Comment: I removed the jar from the project and made the changes in pom.xml like you did. After that it worked fine. It was a problem with my poorly made pom.xml after all.